# printing only first finded match

Tags: awk

I've created a statement which is searching for specific informations in each line (in my case "AAA","BBB" or "CCC"), if there is no such information N/A is printed

> { k=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="AAA") {print $i; k++}
>
> else if ($i=="BBB") {print $i; k++}
>
> else if ($i=="CCC") {print $i; k++}
>
> if(k==0) print "N/A"}

The problem appears when there are two or more "AAA" in the same line. It prints me all found AAA and I would like to stop searching after first finded.

Additionally I would like to stop checking other statements (for BBB or CCC) when AAA contition is true.

For examle, let's say I have an input like that:

> first imput line has AAA
>
> second line has AAA and AAA
>
> third line has BBB and
>
> fourth line has CCC
>
> fifth line has AAA and CCC
>
> last line

in the output I want:

> AAA #(from first line)
>
> AAA #(from second line, but only first found, I don't want two AAA to be printed)
>
> BBB
>
> CCC
>
> AAA #(it found AAA and stop checking condition for CCC)
>
> N/A #(no AAA or BBB or CCC in this line)

Regards,
lucas

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '{
    if (/\<AAA\>/ && /\<BBB\>/ && /\<CCC\>/)
       print
    else
       print "N/A"
}'
```

`\<` and `\>` are word boundary expressions.

Comment: ok, but it prints me all line, and I want only to print that specific information (AAA or BBB or CCC). Moreover it seems that it works only when all 3 statments are true for the line. If one of them is false it prints me N/A.

Comment: Edit your question to show some sample input and your desired output

Comment: I've found an answer, the solution is magic instruction _break_ which stops a loop after first finding. updated code with instruction _break_:       

    { k=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="AAA") {print $i; k++; break}
    else if ($i=="BBB") {print $i; k++; break}
    else if ($i=="CCC") {print $i; k++; break}
    if(k==0) print "N/A"}`
            and all works perfect :)

Answer (score -2):

```
awk '
/\<AAA\>/ {print "AAA"; naflag = 1;}
/\<BBB\>/ {print "BBB"; naflag = 1;}
/\<CCC\>/ {if(cflag == 0) {print "CCC"; naflag = 1; cflag = 1;}}
{if(naflag == 0) print "N/A"; naflag = 0;}
'
```

Comment: That doesn't seem right. Firstly, your curly braces are not balanced properly. Second even if you balance them, it seems your solution is tuned  for this answer. Second `CCC` is not printed, but it is the first `CCC` that prevents second `CCC` not to be printed, not `AAA`.

Comment: your explanation of what you want isn't very clear. Can you explain in more detail?